# What is the conventional way to have C headers with struct function pointers?

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers

What is the conventional way to have C header files and source with function pointers in structs?

For example; I've declared my struct in the header file and all functions and source code in the code file. Is it convention to declare the struct in the source file and assign all function pointers to the proper function?

Comment: An example would be useful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did right , structures are usually placed in header files.

Generally Header files are used to design the framework of the code. The actual code is implemented in another file.

Typically a header file will contain ,

1) Function Prototypes

2) Class Definitions

3) Structure and union Definitions

4) Macros

Refer **[this](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/general-programming/organizing-code-files-in-c-and-c-r1798)** for more insight into organizing code.

Comment: That is a useful article that you've linked to.  However, your answer contains little more than the link, and 'link only' answers are not looked on favourably.   I suggest you find a way to incorporate a brief synopsis of the article, or put a spin on what it says to address the question, such as it is.  Unfortunately, the question itself is quite vague, which makes your job that much harder.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, putting the declaration(both struct and functions) in a header file is a good way to deal with a big program. I think you may have did it rightly, but I still want to give you a suggestion.

Because you didn't give your specific code, I have to use one of my code as a example:

```
#ifndef _COMMAND_H
#define _COMMAND_H

struct Book
{
char isbn[14];
char name[60];
char author[20];
char publisher[20];
char date[9];
float price;
float discount;
};
typedef struct Book BOOK;

struct Node
{
struct Book book;
struct Node *prev;
struct Node *next;
};
typedef struct Node NODE;

int loadArray(BOOK *ary, int num, char * fileName);
int saveAs(BOOK *pBook, int size, char * fileName);
void showAll(BOOK *pBook, int size);
int errCmd();
int menu();

int search(BOOK *pBook, int size, char *isbn);
int sort(BOOK * pBook, int num);
int update(BOOK *pBook, int size, char * isbn);
int delete(BOOK *pBook, int* pSize, char * isbn);
int insert(BOOK *pBook, int *pSize);
int append(BOOK *pBook, int *pSize);

#endif
```

This is a header file for a MIS(to deal with books' information).

I want to tell you that `#ifndef #define #endif` is necessary in a header file which can ensure each header file will be concluded only once. Otherwise, it may have an error "redefinition".

I sincerely hope that my answer can help you. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow; nice answer.  Do you realize that you've not given prototypes for the functions `errCmd()` and `menu()`?  You've declared that they exist and both return an `int`, but you've said nothing about the arguments.  That only means they do not take a variable argument list (unlike `printf()`, which does), but otherwise any arguments could be provided.  This is in contrast to C++ where those same lines declare functions that take no arguments.  To make those into prototypes for C, you must write `int errCmd(void);` and `int menu(void);`.  Try: `gcc -Wmissing-prototypes`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for your comment. I have learned more. I'm studying C++ now. The comparison between C and C++ is what I'm doing through my study.